# Changing DataContexts, reinvoking Loaded event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I use a MySQL connection to get a DataTable from a database and load it into a datagrid:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = db.Get_Data();
```

Later on in the program I have buttons and events that change the data in the Grid:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = db.Get_Other_Data();
```

This works great. However, I am having issues resizing the columns after changing the DataContext property.

If I go:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = db.Get_Other_Data();
dataGrid1.Columns[0] = 15;
```

I get an exception - I learned that the data hasn't been loaded into the Grid yet so it throws an index out of bound exception.

So I tried looking at events like:

```
DataContextChanged - Doesn't wait till data is loaded
Loaded - Only works when the first DataContext is set, not on all
```

How can I reinvoke Loaded on all the different DataContext initializations? Or some other event?

Comment: Does this line really work `dataGrid1.Columns[0] = 15;`? Or would that actually fail? It appears that you're setting the column itself to 15. Did you just miss the property `Width`?

Comment: Also, have you tried consuming the `LayoutUpdated` event?

Comment: Yeah i missed the line width typing it out. Let me try layout updated!

Comment: Yep, that works great. So anyone having the same issue where you need to wait for the data to load into the grid, use layout updated! Thanks Michael.